# Define coordinate at beginning of document

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a few TikZ pictures and I want to use the same coordinates for some of them. can I define the coordinates with `\newcommand` or something like this so I can easily use them in every picture without copy paste the whole thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to define a new style using `execute at begin picture`. Should you want to define the same coordinates in *all* `tikzpicture`s, you can add that style to the `every picture` style.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  defcoords/.style={
    execute at begin picture={
      \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
      \coordinate (a) at (1,1);
   }
 },
%every picture/.append style={defcoords} % will apply this to all tikzpictures
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[defcoords]
\draw [->] (o) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

A simple macro can be defined with the coordinate definitions, e.g.:

```
\newcommand*{\CommonCoordinates}{%
  \path
    (0, 0) coordinate (origin)
    (1, 2) coordinate (A)
    (7, 3) coordinate (B)
    % ...
  ;%
}
```

Then:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \CommonCoordinates
  % ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```